How to hide some properties in UNDO window *depending on the execute() result
I'm making an operator which has multiple properties in the UNDO window:

Depending on the result which happened inside the execute() function some of these properties would be relevant and some would not.
*The question:
How can I dynamically set some of these properties being shown while others being hidden *depending on the result  of execute() ?

Use a Custom Interface.
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    
    if self.condition == True:
        row = layout .row()
        row.prop(self, "property1")


This is exactly what I needed. HUGE thanks !
